# Company seats registration flow - looking for alternatives/opinions

Tags: registration, signup-signon

I'm trying to verify whether the company seats registration flow I built makes sense or not and I'd like to hear about other ways/options/flow.

As a part of my SaaS product, I want companies to be able to purchase one of three packages. Each package provides a different number of seats, as shown below:

- Plan A: 5 - 10 members
- Plan B: 11 - 50 members
- Plan C: 51 - 100 members

The current sign up/registration flow is as follows:

1. Company's representative (e.g. head of HR) selects a package which reflects the amount of seats needed for the company
2. The company's representative provides details: name, title, phone and email address which must be with the organization's email suffix (e.g. @mynicecar.com)
3. Payment form: the company's representative completes the payment
4. Once the payment is confirmed, each user who signs up with his organizational email address (e.g. john@mynicecar.com) will  automatically get permission to the product with no need for pay as it uses a seat from the seats pool

Any other flows you can come up with? Maybe implementing a coupon/code based seat management (each time a code is used, it's being taken from the pool) instead of tying it to the organization's email suffix, etc...

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

One alternative to this what I can think of is like what Netflix do, 
This will reduce burden related to registrations at your end.

**One representative(parent) purchases the pack and is allowed to create other(child) profiles.**

Flow would be like :

1. Company's representative (e.g. Head of HR) selects a package.
2. After the payment is made you allocate them a parent account. Now parent account can add no. of child accounts as per the package.
3. To add child accounts, the parent account will have to do is add basic details like 
   Name, email, phone, title etc.

**Benefits**

1. Less burden at your end.
2. Parent account will have more control on managing other accounts and can also make edits if required.

Answer (score 0):

Look at how atlassian cloud subscription is made, it has a checkbox between your solution and the previos answer ( https://ux.stackexchange.com/a/121053/16685 )

If the company runs over its limit it sends a warning email to the admin account holder that from next month they will pay more. The customer service can help them out if they just accidentally added a seat or forgot to cancel someone who doesn’t need it anymore :)

It has the benefit that it conveniently rises prices as their demand grows instead of blocking them - trust me, their accounting will send a heads-up anyway if the bill was more than the prev one :)

Answer (score 0):

My view is that what this flow is missing is: how end user (say HR head- if it's a small organization or someone in HR team or someone else altogether if it is an MNC with lots of users) will want to use such an account.

I feel that parent accounts are better in such case as this decouples process that your organization has with what the customer organization may be following and people who may be authorized to control the seats.

Also, this removes the burden of trying to customize the flows for every new large customer that you may get...

One usability issue with upfront seat nomination is: if someone opted for 51-100 package entering emails of 100 people can be an amazingly painful task...

So go for 
1. 'Lazy Seat Allocation- at a time of end customer's choice and comfort'
2. Upfront and immediate subscription without the need to identify everyone in the list by company emails
3. You will need to implement a dashboard in this case for the same so that people can use the seats in a few days etc.

(FYI: Adobe has similar seat allocation for Creative Cloud but its rather formal UI- little too formal)

Answer (score 0):

Step 1 assumes that the representative knows the number of seats they need.

If they don't know, then they're likely to either quit the process in order to get a definitive count (and possibly never come back), or make a guess then try to figure out how to change the order when they're wrong.

So please consider a flow that provides an easy way for your customers to update their orders. This will, of course, require you to both add to and delete seats and to add charges and provide refunds.

Answer (score 0):

The Netflix flow with registration form (including social login button) should be optimal https://www.useronboard.com/how-netflix-onboards-new-users/ 
In first step account owner can just click social login button and on second screen select package and pay.

Allowing company users to join if they are in domain is very convenient. Good that you have it.
Its used by Slack https://www.useronboard.com/how-slack-onboards-new-users/?slide=40
We use it for all our internal tools, like https://selleo.com/portfolio/meritmoney

BTW You can also check out some tips on How to Optimize Registration Form for Higher Conversion here
https://selleo.com/blog/how-to-optimize-registration-form-conversion-rate